# If a code C = the dual of its dual, must C be linear?

Tags: coding-theory

If C is a linear code, then C = the dual of the dual of C.

Is the converse true also?

Comment: Looking at Wikipedia, the dual of a code $C$ seems to only be defined if $C$ is linear. Do you have another definition?

Comment: @Samuel Yes I saw that entry too, that's why I had to ask here. My definition of dual code applies to all codes, not just linear ones. Do a keyword search for "dual c" in this page and refer to the first instance http://www.mth.msu.edu/~jhall/classes/codenotes/Linear.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The dual of $C$ is linear even if $C$ is not.

(I just not that I exactly quoted the pdf you linked)

Comment: Oh! Hehe. Cheers!